# Ability to change the type of flag? Or have an unflag option?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flagging

I come across questions, when sometimes I find the need for flagging it. But, sometimes in confusion / or due to error I flag it wrongly.
And when I again try to flag, it says, *you've already flagged this post for moderator attention*.
Shouldn't the users be allowed to change the type of flag? Or should there be an option to *unflag* the already flagged question? If no, then is there any specific reason behind this?

Comment: The network-level discussion of this issue is here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87660/flag-removal-is-it-possible-to-remove-your-flag-or-otherwise-indicate-it-should

Answer (score 3):

I second this.  Yesterday, I posted comments asking somebody with a (IMHO) very confused question to improve specific points.  This morning, the user had added some comments that did not improve things (they made the question even more confusing - again IMHO).  So I flagged it as "low quality".

Then, I few hours later, the OP *had* cleaned up the question. There is now no longer a valid reason to have it flagged as "low quality", but there seem to be no way for me to remove the flag.

Answer (score 3):

It's now possible to retract a raised flag. Once flagged a post, clicking on *flag* will show a dialog box similar to the following one.

> [image]

Instead of the *Flag Answer* or *Flag Question* button, there is the *Retract Flag* button that allows to retract the raised flag, and eventually flag the post for another reason.

Comment: It makes sense to force users to think well before flagging. But, I am not sure what happens when more number of flags get declined? Is the user banned for some days from flagging? Similar to banning from editing if more number of edits get declined? And I think the spam flags also gets marked as useful if the post gets deleted after sufficient number of flags.

Comment: In the case the user's flag weight would become 0, the flags would be automatically ignored. It is difficult it happens, though; you should keep flagging many posts that didn't need any attention.